# calling applet functions from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, applet

This is probably really basic and Simple but my Gogle-foo is failing me.

I have an applet embedded on the page via an Object tag.

It has method `public void foo(String bar)`

Now I want to call `foo` with `baz`,

So I do

```
   getElemntById('myApplet').foo('baz')
```

Which doesn't work, and I cant get info from Google-foo on what is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be getElementById (there's a missing e)

getElementById should work, so the problem could anywhere. You've got a guide in

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html

It would be good to know the detailed problem (e.g. Javascript error, reflection exception)